# android create and read xml from sdcard

Tags: android, xml

I use 2 button, 1st button to create xml file in sdcard
and 2nd button to read this xml.
this is my code :

```
String xml_root;
ListView lv_emp;
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_AGE = "age";
List<HashMap<String, String>> empHashmap;
List<ClassEmp> empList = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_empacc);

    xml_root = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + "\n" +
            "<employees>" + "\n" +
            "\t" + "<emp>" + "\n" +
            "\t" +  "\t" + "<name>" + "jame" + "</name>" + "\n" +
            "\t" +  "\t" + "<age>" + "17" + "</age>" + "\n" +
            "\t" +  "</emp>" + "\n" +
            "\t" +  "<emp>" + "\n" +
            "\t" +  "\t" + "<name>" + "natalie" + "</name>" + "\n" +
            "\t" +  "\t" + "<age>" + "20" + "</age>" + "\n" +
            "\t" + "</emp>" + "\n" +
            "</employees>";

    Button bt_create2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_createfileT2);
    bt_create2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                File newFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TestFolder");
                if (!newFolder.exists()) {
                    newFolder.mkdir();
                }

                File file = new File(newFolder, "Test" + ".xml");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                    myOutWriter.append(xml_root);
                    myOutWriter.close();
                    fOut.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("e: " + e);
            }
        }
    });

    Button bt_read2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_readfileT2);
    bt_read2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                lv_emp = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_Emp);
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "TestFolder/Test.xml");
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
                XmlPullParserEmp parser_Emp = new XmlPullParserEmp();
                empList = parser_Emp.parse(is);
                BinderDataEmp bd_Emp = new BinderDataEmp(Empacc.this, empHashmap);
                lv_emp.setAdapter(bd_Emp);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

with this code, it was create Test.xml in TestFolder on sdcard.
but I can't read it.
how to fix it ?

Comment: please share the error that you're getting while reading the file.

Comment: I see java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcardTestFolder/Test.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) , at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416) , at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>

Comment: you can clearly see in the error that you don't have a `/` between sdcard and TestFolder.

Comment: thank you, I has answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most probably missing /(slash) during reading the file

Use this and retry:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/TestFolder/Test.xml");
```

Comment: I see error org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Comments may not contain -- (position:COMMENT  , @3:13 in java.io.InputStreamReader@5355598c)  ,  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readComment(KXmlParser.java:564)

Comment: Same line of code running in my android studio. Check for permission 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> or your XmlPullParserEmp parser_Emp = new XmlPullParserEmp(); class might have issue.

Comment: [`Comments may not contain --`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r1/xml/src/main/java/com/android/org/kxml2/io/KXmlParser.java#570) literally means what it says. KXmlParser always expects `>` (comment closing tag) character after 2 or more consecutive hyphens (`--`).